# What's the difference between "The process is no easy task" and "The process is not an easy task"?

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure

When reading a passage in VOA English, I found a sentence:

> The process is no easy task.

It comes to me another sentence:

> The process is not an easy task.

What's the difference between them?

Comment: They are 99% synonyms.

Comment: According to the website [Difference between no and not](https://www.englishgrammar.org/difference-2/), I think the first sentence means: The process is not any easy task. "an" and "any" is the difference.

Comment: This applies only to nouns. Like in: **No task is easy.**

Comment: In dictionary, I found **no** can be a **determine** which means **not one; not a; not any**, so they are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**No easy thing**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no%20easy%20thing) and [**no easy matter**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no%20easy%20matter) as Merriam-Webster states mean: *something that is not easy to do or bear*.

[Dictionary.Com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/no) explains this definition as ***not a*** (used before an adjective to convey the opposite of the adjective's meaning)

- His recovery was **no** small miracle.

**No** can also be followed by comparative adjectives and adverbs:

- No fewer than forty men.
- No more quickly than before.

According to this knowledge we can assume that **"no easy task"** equals **"not an easy task"**.

Comment: According to the website [Difference between no and not](https://www.englishgrammar.org/difference-2/), I think the first sentence means: The process is not any easy task. "an" and "any" is the difference.

Comment: In dictionary, I found **no** can be a **determine** which means **not one; not a; not any**, so they are same.

Answer (score 2):

I am not an English native speaker.

I would just say that **there's no difference** in the meaning, that is: *There's nothing simple in this process*.

So, I agree with @SovereignSun. The sentences are the same and they could be intended as synonyms.